# Confusion about compactness, relative and sequential compactness

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

I think I have confused myself a bit with compactness.

For a metric space $X$ and a subset $A$ we have the following:

(i) $X$ compact $\iff$ $X$ sequentially compact
(ii) $X$ compact and $A$ closed $\implies$ $A$ compact
(iii) $A$ relatively compact $\iff$ $A$ relatively sequentially compact

Let's consider $A$ metric space on its own: (i) would imply that $A$ is compact iff $A$ is sequentially compact which, since $A$ is closed in $A$, is equivalent to $A$ being relatively sequetially compact. So let $A$ be sequentially compact. Than $A$ is compact which means that

1. for all open covers $\bigcup_{j\in J}U_{j}=A$ there exists finite subcovers (note that $U_{j}\subseteq A$).

However, $A$ being compact as a subset of the metric space $X$ means that

2. for all open covers $\bigcup_{i\in I}O_{i}\supseteq A$ there exist finite subcovers (note that this time $O_{i}$ doesn't necessarily have to be a subset of $A$).

Clearly, 1 and 2 are not equivalent.

Question 1: Which one of the two (1 or 2) follow from the fact that $A$ is sequentially compact?

Question 2: By (iii) and (i), $A$ being sequentially compact would imply that $A$ is compact and relatively compact. So relative compactness and compactness would be the same thing in metric spaces.

Question 3: Finally, for a subset $A$ of a metric space $X$, is compactness the same as sequential compactness?

Comment: (iii) should read $\ A \ relatively \ compact \iff A \ relatively \ sequentially \ compact$.

Comment: Relative compactness depends on the ambient metric space $X$, because closure is involved. So yes, a metric space is compact if and only if it is relatively compact (in itself), which is not very interesting. Relative compactness is interesting when you consider $A\subsetneq X$ as $A$ might not be compact, but its closure could be.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks, edited it.

Comment: @Brifa What does A being compact mean than? That for every open cover that lies in A we find a finite subcover or for every open cover that lies in X we find a finite subcover?

Comment: You need to consider that openness is a relative concept. Since every compact set in a metric space is also closed, you will, in general, not find an open cover of a compact set $A\subset X$ consisting of open subsets of $X$. However, if you equip $A$ with the induced metric, then the open subsets of $A$ are precisely the sets $A\cap U$ where $U$ is an open subset of $X$. Then you can cover $A$ by such open subsets of $A$ and $A$ is compact if and only if every such cover admits an open subcover.

Comment: Note also that compactness is independent of the ambient space, so $A$ is compact as a subset of $X$ if and only if $A$, equipped with the induced metric, is compact as a metric space of its own. So your two assertions above are indeed equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful: relative compactness is not an “absolute” concept. Similarly for relative sequential compactness.

For instance, $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is relatively compact as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, but it's not compact.

You cannot extract finite subcovers of $A$ from open covers of $A$ *with open sets in* $A$ (which aren't open in $\mathbb{R}$).

To the contrary, compactness is an absolute concept. A subspace $C$ is compact as a subspace if and only if it is compact as a space by itself (with the relative topology or induced metric, if you're bound to metric spaces). Try and write a proof of this.

In metric spaces, compactness and sequential compactness are the same, because each point has a countable basis of neighborhoods.

Comment: Thanks, that really clarifies it for me. To sum up, to show that a subset of a metric space is (rel.) compact, I equivalently can prove that it is (rel.) seq. compact.

Comment: @user1060931 Yes, the two notions are equivalent on metric spaces.